# OSX El Capitan sqlalchemy Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, osx-elcapitan

The python in this app is running from a docker container. The container is running in network mode: "host".

I'm having trouble connecting to a MySQL database through the python package sqlalchemy. I get the following error.

> OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL
>   server on '127.0.0.1' (111)") None None

The following terminal command works fine

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u my_user --password='password' db -e "SHOW TABLES;"
enter code here
```

Maybe sqlalchemy isn't using the correct configuration you say? I have printed out the configuration in a debug line right before the first connection to MySQL:

```
  print config.get('repository', 'host') // 127.0.0.1
  print config.get('repository', 'user') // my_user
  print config.get('repository', 'passwd') // password
```

Maybe that configuration still isn't making it into sqlalchemy? Lets print out the engine string

```
  engine = getUnaffiliatedEngine()
  print engine //Engine(mysql://my_user:***@127.0.0.1:3306)
  with engine.connect() as connection:
    for s in statements:
      if s.strip():
        connection.execute(s)
```

Maybe there's more than 1 version of mysql running? Only one process is running:

```
ps -ef | grep mysql
```

> 74 15459     1   0 10:14AM ??         0:00.80
>   /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql

Maybe that user doesn't have access to the database?

```
mysql> select User, Host from mysql.user;

+------+--------------------------+
| User | Host                     |
+------+--------------------------+
|my_user 127.0.0.1                |
| root | 127.0.0.1                |
| root | ::1                      |
|      | localhost                |
| root | localhost                |
+------+--------------------------+
```

Similarly 'show databases' shows that the db exists. I have granted all privs to that user for every database. I have flushed the privs too.

Maybe some kind of firewall rule is stopping the connection? I use little snitch, and the entire firewall has been taken down to test this.

I don't even know what else to debug at this point. Here is a reduced version of the python script throwing the connection error:

```
DSN_FORMAT = "mysql://%(user)s:%(passwd)s@%(host)s:%(port)s"

def getDSN():
  return DSN_FORMAT % dict(config.items("repository"))

def getUnaffiliatedEngine():
  return create_engine(getDSN())

def reset(offline=False):
  config.loadConfig()
  dbName = config.get('repository', 'db')
  print config.get('repository', 'host')
  print config.get('repository', 'user')
  print config.get('repository', 'passwd')

  resetDatabaseSQL = (
      "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS %(database)s; "
      "CREATE DATABASE %(database)s;" % {"database": dbName})
  statements = resetDatabaseSQL.split(";")

  engine = getUnaffiliatedEngine()
  print engine
  with engine.connect() as connection:
    for s in statements:
      if s.strip():
        connection.execute(s)
```

Here is the output for `tcpdump -i lo0 port 3306` :

```
11:44:41.224036 IP localhost.58797 > localhost.mysql: Flags [P.], seq 3915736486:3915736498, ack 2134634265, win 12519, options [nop,nop,TS val 980567261 ecr 980503692], length 12
11:44:41.224105 IP localhost.mysql > localhost.58797: Flags [.], ack 12, win 12737, options [nop,nop,TS val 980567261 ecr 980567261], length 0
11:44:41.224178 IP localhost.mysql > localhost.58797: Flags [P.], seq 1:19, ack 12, win 12737, options [nop,nop,TS val 980567261 ecr 980567261], length 18
11:44:41.224218 IP localhost.58797 > localhost.mysql: Flags [.], ack 19, win 12519, options [nop,nop,TS val 980567261 ecr 980567261], length 0
11:45:07.422776 IP localhost.58796 > localhost.mysql: Flags [P.], seq 2953728354:2953728366, ack 432872138, win 12483, options [nop,nop,TS val 980593366 ecr 980533534], length 12
11:45:07.422807 IP localhost.mysql > localhost.58796: Flags [.], ack 12, win 12729, options [nop,nop,TS val 980593366 ecr 980593366], length 0
11:45:07.422856 IP localhost.mysql > localhost.58796: Flags [P.], seq 1:19, ack 12, win 12729, options [nop,nop,TS val 980593366 ecr 980593366], length 18
11:45:07.422877 IP localhost.58796 > localhost.mysql: Flags [.], ack 19, win 12482, options [nop,nop,TS val 980593366 ecr 980593366], length 0
```

MySQL 5.6
OSX El Capitan 10.11.6

Comment: Could you show the actual code that is giving the error? Or at least a reduced version of it.

Comment: I agree with @gsi-frank - a reduced example with just the plain SQLAlchemy engine and [connection setup (like in its docs)](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#module-sqlalchemy.engine) would be helpful here (both for you to simplify debugging, and for the question here on SO).

Comment: @gsi-frank done

Comment: `111` is `Connection refused`. So your MySQL server probably is only listening on the local interface, and for some reason your connection attempt seems to get routed over the external interface. Googling "little snitch localhost connection" turns up a couple issues people were having, even with it disabled.

Comment: @MarkJones Could you do `tcpdump -i lo0  port 3306` before executing the script? Make sure that anybody else is trying to connect to your local MySQL while testing this. The idea is to see from which address you are connecting to the MySQL server.

Comment: @gsi-frank I updated the question, so stupid for not mentioning this. The python is running in a docker container, but the network mode is 'host' so it should not change anything. It should just be acting like a normal process...."SHOULD"..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That last comment you wrote is very important and probably the reason of the problem.

I'm pretty sure that your Docker container has its own loopback interface with an address 127.0.0.1 that is different than your OSX loopback interface where you have running the MySQL.

I recommend you put your MySQL listening on an address that is visible from inside your container. You can debug that config easily making `telnet ip_address 3306` from inside your container.

Comment: If anyone stumbles upon this, using --network='host' for Docker on OSX does not work as intended, and it will not be fixed by Docker. Docker on OSX uses VMs, the --network='host' argument is completely broken here. Reading through comments on Docker forums, the issue is ignored and there will not be any efforts going forward to fix this.